# WPF Image tooltip locking file

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a listbox that shows images , the list gives the user option to open the file with the default image editor. In the list the image has a tooltip wich shows a larger version of the image.

My problem is that when the tooltip has been shown the image is locked and if the user tries to edit the image, he will a get a access sharing violation when he tries to save.

The xaml is very simple

```
<Image x:Name="_thumbImage" Source="{Binding Path}" >                  
                            <Image.ToolTip>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path,BindsDirectlyToSource=True,IsAsync=False}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="300" Width="300"></Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Image.ToolTip>

                        </Image>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly create a `BitmapImage` that would cache the image in memory and release the file. Note it's not necessary to load the image twice, so I'm putting it in a resource.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources> 
     <BitmapImage x:Key="Source" UriSource="{Binding Path}" />
  </Grid.Resources>                    
  <Image x:Name="_thumbImage" Source="{StaticResource Source}">
    <Image.ToolTip>
      <Grid>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource Source}" Stretch="Fill" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Height="300" Width="300">
        </Image>
      </Grid>
    </Image.ToolTip>
  </Image>
</Grid>
```